# R Programming: How do I control the order in a grouped stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following graph and I would like "InProcess" to be below "Investigating".  I thought reordering the state factor would do it, but all it does is affect the order the legend is printed.  How would you accomplish this?

[image]

Here is the code and dataset that creates this graph.

Data:

```
Date    Identified  InProcess   Fixed   NotFixed    Duplicate
11/12/2015  22  43  10  5   8
11/19/2015  11  21  11  9   27
11/26/2015  24  10  10  4   13
12/3/2015   39  11  4   2   17
12/10/2015  36  11  11  8   8
12/17/2015  32  9   9   4   7
12/24/2015  20  6   4   12  13
12/31/2015  19  4   5   3   2
1/7/2016    21  3   5   4   2
```

.

```
plotgraph <- function() {
  require(ggplot2)
  require(reshape2)
  require(data.table)

  testdata <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "Date    Identified  InProcess   Fixed   Inactionable    Duplicate
                       11/12/2015  22  43  10  5   8
                       11/19/2015  11  21  11  9   27
                       11/26/2015  24  10  10  4   13
                       12/3/2015   39  11  4   2   17
                       12/10/2015  36  11  11  8   8
                       12/17/2015  32  9   9   4   7
                       12/24/2015  20  6   4   12  13
                       12/31/2015  19  4   5   3   2
                       1/7/2016    21  3   5   4   2")
  setnames(testdata,c("Date","Investigating",   "InProcess",    "Fixed",    "Inactionable", "Duplicate"))
  testdata<-testdata[1:5,]

  testdata$Date <- as.Date(testdata$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
  df <- melt(testdata,id.vars="Date")
  df$group <- ''

  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if ((df$variable[i] == "Investigating") | (df$variable[i] == "InProcess")) {
      df$group[i] <- ".Open"
    }
    else {
      df$group[i] <- as.character("Closed")
    }
  }

  setnames(df,c("date","state","count","group"))
  df$state <- relevel(df$state,"Investigating")
  cols <-  c(  Investigating = "coral2",InProcess = "coral4",Fixed = "olivedrab4", Inactionable = "olivedrab3", Duplicate =  "olivedrab1")

  df<- transform(df, 
           state.ord  = factor(
             df$state,
             levels=c( 'Investigating','InProcess','Fixed','Inactionable','Duplicate' ),
             ordered =TRUE))


  a <- ggplot(df,aes(x=group,y=count,fill=state,order=state.ord)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack",aes(fill=state.ord)) +
    facet_grid(~date) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=cols,name="") +
    xlab("") + ylab("Count of Issues")

  a
}
```

Comment: Can you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2?rq=1 (or any of the other closely related questions)?

Comment: I don't get nearly the same plot using your data. plus you have left out some factor levels so I get NAs. did you try running this code before posting it? also you should add the packages that you are using

Comment: Sort of.  If I use the method ggplot(df[order(df$state,decreasing=F),].... I end up with processed on the bottom but now Fixed is on top.  The problem just switched to the green column

Comment: @rawr, I edited it to include the full dataset and code. Sorry about that

Comment: you can just order the variables differently and it will change the bar orders, as in `df <- df[order(-xtfrm(df$state.ord)), ]` but that will reverse everything, not sure if you want that, too. but that's the general strategy--ggplot will order the bars how they appear in the data

Comment: Your reordering of the factor worked just fine - it's just ordering things in the reverse order from what you want. Put a `rev()` around your vector in `levels = c(...)` and everything will match up.

Comment: If you want to preserve the current legend ordering, after reversing the levels add `reverse = TRUE` to `scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: @Gregor, I reversed the order and now the red bar is correct, but now the green bar is flipped.  I want to maintain the green bars order but flip the red

Comment: I got it now. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This section was added/modified to get the correct graph

```
df<- transform(df, 
           state.ord  = factor(
             df$state,
             levels=c('Duplicate','Inactionable','Fixed' ,'Investigating','InProcess' ),
             ordered =TRUE))

  df <- df[order(-xtfrm(df$state.ord)), ]
```