# ggplot change stack oder in barplot

Tags: r

I have the following plot where I need to get the blue bar (fail) to the top. I tried with `order` but it is not making the expected change. What is the issue with the order?

```
ggplot(a, aes(fill=Var1, y=value, x=Var2, order("pass","fail"))) 
       +geom_bar( stat="identity", position="fill") + labs(x = "Subject", y="Pass/Fail Percentage") 
       + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Result"))
```

[image]

This is my data

```
Var1    Var2    value
pass    Maths   865     
fail    Maths   135     
pass    Reading 910     
fail    Reading 90      
pass    Writing 886     
fail    Writing 114
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your dataset?

Comment: @HarroCyranka added data

Comment: Is your Var1 a factor? I could not reproduce the error with the data.

Comment: @HarroCyranka yes Val1,Val2 are factors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend releveling the factor, like this.

```
a %>% mutate(Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = c("fail", "pass"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=Var1, y=value, x=Var2)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity", position="fill") + labs(x = "Subject", y="Pass/Fail Percentage") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Result"))
```

[image]