# A tidy way to order x-axis in stacked bar by subset of fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyverse, forcats

I have a **dataframe** `GTs.df` of *genotypes* for 8 *genes* across 8 different *genetic lines*. `"NA"`s represent ambiguous sequencing calls. (There are few heterozygotes `"Aa"` because these are inbred lines).

```
GTs.df <- data.frame(Gene = rep(c("Zm1","Zm2","Zm3","Zm4","Zm5","Zm6","Zm7","Zm8"), each=8),
  Line = rep(c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8"), times = 8),
  Genotype = c(rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(2, 1, 5, 0)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(4, 0, 1, 3)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(4, 1, 3, 0)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(3, 0, 4, 1)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(4, 0, 3, 1)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(5, 1, 2, 0)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(1, 0, 3, 4)),
               rep(c("aa", "Aa", "AA", "NA"), times = c(1, 1, 6, 0))
               )
  )
```

I want to compare the **distribution** of genotypes across the lines for *each gene*, so I make this **stacked bar plot** initially:

```
GTs.df %>%
  filter(Genotype != "NA") %>%
  mutate(Genotype = fct_relevel(Genotype, 
                                  c("AA", "Aa", "aa"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Gene,
      fill = Genotype) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack",
           stat = "count") + 
  ylab("Number of Lines")
```

[image]

But the problem is that I want the Genes/columns **ordered by number of `"aa"`** so that it is more *readable*. I can reorder the Genes via `fct_reorder` as suggested by [tbradley](https://community.rstudio.com/t/a-tidy-way-to-order-stacked-bar-chart-by-fill-subset/5134) / [48748250/FilipW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748250/order-x-axis-in-stacked-bar-by-subset-of-fill) and demonstrated below...

```
GTs.df %>%
  filter(Genotype != "NA") %>%
  mutate(Genotype = fct_relevel(Genotype, 
                                  c("AA", "Aa", "aa")),
         Gene = fct_reorder(Gene,
                            as.numeric(Genotype),
                            .fun = mean)
         ) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Gene,
      fill = Genotype) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack",
           stat = "count") + 
  ylab("Number of Lines")
```

[image]

As you can see, this does order the Genes/columns pretty well via sorting *by proportion*, but this is **imperfect** in this case because of *missing data points* and *greater than 2 levels*. You can see the last Gene (Zm2) has fewer "aa" lines than the Gene before it but does have a higher proportion/mean of "aa".

I also tried a variation of this using `sum` instead of `mean`.

```
GTs.df %>%
  filter(Genotype != "NA") %>%
  mutate(Genotype = fct_relevel(Genotype, 
                                  c("AA", "Aa", "aa")),
         Gene = fct_reorder(Gene,
                            as.numeric(Genotype),
                            .fun = sum)
         ) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Gene,
      fill = Genotype) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack",
           stat = "count") + 
  ylab("Number of Lines")
```

[image]

It also almost works, but is still **imperfect**. Gene Zm4 has fewer "aa"s than the column before it, I guess because Zm4 has more total datapoints to contribute to the sum.

*Ideally*, I would want to use some sort of **count function** instead, but neither `n` or `count` work for me, no matter what *class* I change `Genotype` to. (Many combos so I spared the long, depressing list of error messages).

I did find a **non-tidy solution** from [48748250/talat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748250/order-x-axis-in-stacked-bar-by-subset-of-fill) that arranges the columns *by count/absolute frequency* of "aa" *as desired*:

```
gene_lvls <- names(sort(table(GTs.df[GTs.df$Genotype == "aa", "Gene"])))

GTs.df %>%
  filter(Genotype != "NA") %>%
  mutate(Genotype = fct_relevel(Genotype, 
                                  c("AA", "Aa", "aa"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = factor(Gene, 
                 levels = gene_lvls),
      fill = Genotype) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack",
           stat = "count") + 
  ylab("Number of Lines")
```

[image]

But I am *hoping* there's a **tidy/dplyr/forcat-friendly way** to achieve this, partly for *learning/understanding* and partly for *pickiness/aethetic pleasure*. Based on the number of similar forum questions, I have a feeling other people would be pleased by such a solution too.
**Bonus points** if the solution has a **secondary filter/tie-breaker** when multiple columns have *equal number of "aa"*, as demonstrated by Zm2, Zm3 and Zm5 in the above plot.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort!

Here are some other forum pages that are somewhat related:

[R ggplot2 Reorder stacked plot ?](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-ggplot2-reorder-stacked-plot/23912)

[How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2)

[sort columns with categorical variables by numerical varables in stacked barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590732/sort-columns-with-categorical-variables-by-numerical-varables-in-stacked-barplot)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `fct_inorder` after calculating some Gene-wise metrics like # of aa an total number of lines. This provides a pretty flexible way of creating whatever sorting metric you want, which could involve multiple tie-breakers.

```
GTs.df %>%
  filter(Genotype != "NA") %>%
  mutate(Genotype = fct_relevel(Genotype, 
                                c("AA", "Aa", "aa"))) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  mutate(num_aa = sum(Genotype == "aa"),
         ttl_lines = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(num_aa, ttl_lines) %>%        # Define your tie-breakers here
  mutate(Gene = fct_inorder(Gene)) %>%  # Assign factor in order of appearance 
  
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Gene,
      fill = Genotype) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack",
           stat = "count") + 
  ylab("Number of Lines")
```

[image]