# Assign colors to groups in stacked area charts, R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I made a stacked area charts using ggplot2 like this

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_area()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red", "yellow", "purple", "deeppink", "blue"))
```

In the group variable appear 6 different strings values identifying the groups, how can I assign one precise color to each group?

Furthermore is it possible to order the groups in the chart with the same order as they appear in the data I am passing to the function? Otherwise how can I decide the order?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you got and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether it's `fill` or `color`. The plot type also doesn't matter.

You can use key-value pairs to specify the color or fill as long as the values provided in `values` argument is inside the column for coloring.

In following example, `setosa`, `versicolor` and `virginica` are three unique values in `Species` column.

```r
ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(
        "setosa" = "black",
        "versicolor" = "red",
        "virginica" = "green"
    ))
```

[image]

Comment: I substituted the scale_fill_manual function with:
 scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "MAXC" = "black",
    "MAXD" = "red",
    "MINC" = "yellow",
    "MIND" = "purple",
    "RND" = "blue",
    "NO" = "deeppink"
  ))
the "MAXC" ecc are the string representing the groups, but it didn't work and the standard colors of the chart have been used.

Comment: I had to use still the scale_fill_manual function instead of the scale_color_manual but passed the key, value list as you said, and it worked. What about the order?

Comment: To change the order of stacking, you need to make `group` an ordered factor. `forcats` is a handy package for dealing with factors, and `forcats::fct_inorder()` should help you put your groups in order of appearance.  https://forcats.tidyverse.org/

Comment: If you use `fill` in `aes()` then use `scale_fill_*`, if you use `color` in `aes()` then use `scale_color_*`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2 ; If what you ask is irrelevant to your question. Either ask a new question, or modify your original question.