# Stacked barplot order by unique factors per bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found posts like [How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2) where the order of factors can be re-leveled when the bar plots have the same factors in them, or using a numeric to order the stacked bars, but I want to create a stacked bar plots where each stack has its own unique factors.

```
test <- data.frame(unique_factors = c("stack", "bars", "in", "this", "exact", "order"),
           length = c(1,5,3,2,6,1),
           groups = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"))

ggplot(test, aes(x = groups, y = length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = unique_factors, levels=c("stack", "bars", "in", "this", "exact", "order")))
```

## Current Output

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this effect - if so, how? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, I'm sorry but I'm unsure what you're asking - I'm using the `groups` as the x-axis for my repex here and would like to stack each group by the `unique_factors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have used the `forcats` package:

`fct_inorder` puts them in the order we have in our data.frame and `fct_rev` reverses the ordering:

```r
library(forcats)
ggplot(test, aes(x = groups, y = length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           aes(fill = fct_rev(fct_inorder(unique_factors))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to refactor the unique_factors!

```
test$unique_factors <- factor(test$unique_factors, levels = c("stack", "bars", "in", "this", "exact", "order"))
```

Comment: which can be also done with `test$unique_factors <- factor(test$unique_factors, levels = unique(test$unique_factors))` instead of typing them all out.